# How can I get XML prefix declarations from root element with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, objectify

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:foo="http://example.com/bar">
  <foo:Child>yikes</foo:Child>
</Root>
```

test.py:

```
from lxml import objectify
root = objectify.fromstring(file('test.xml').read())
print root.attrib
```

Outputs:

```
{}
```

How can I get the prefix declarations? I.e. something like:

```
{
  "xmlns": "http://example.com",
  "xmlns:foo": "http://example.com/bar"}
```

UPDATE:

`root.keys()`, `root.items()` and `root.values()` yield `[]`, `[]` and `{}`, respectively.

Comment: You tried root.keys? root.items()? root.values()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element` objects have a property called `nsmap` which contains all known namespaces for the element's context. Mentioned in the [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

```
>>> root.nsmap
{None: "http://example.com", "foo": "http://example.com/bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.attrib)
```

Output:

> {'xmlns':'http://example.com' 'xmlns:foo'='http://example.com/bar'}

Hope that helps